# Moving a domain with Email configured

Tags: exchange-2010, mx-record, domain-name

I have an MX records setup on my domain working with my Exchange 2010 server. Emails are working great.

I want to transfer my domain to another provider. So far I have done the following:

- Configured DNS records including MX records at the new provider.
- Moved nameservers to the new provider

Before I change the IPS tag and start the transfer is there anything else I need to do?

I am probably being paranoid but I don't want emails to stop working after the transfer and be forced to move things back. I have done everything I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing you can do before you move providers is lower your TTL on your domain. 5 minutes is fine, obviously, this will not actually be effective until the current TTL has expired, so if it's 24 hours, you should change it to 5 minutes, then wait 24 hours.

Since you are using the new nameservers already, when you actually update the MX records to point to the new provider, there will be a much shorter time before external servers pick up on the change.